# blurry layout on xhdpi screens

Tags: android, maps, resolution

I've developed a map-based android app. As I want my app to be used with most of android smartphones.
 I've added graphic resources for each type of screen resolution, from `ldpi` to `xhdpi` , nevertheless, when I use my app with `xhdpi` devices (i.e. Samsung galaxy s3 or Google nexus 4), and also with Google nexus 7, images and also the map are blurry.
Could anybody tell me why?

Thank you all!!
Akis

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following folder naming.

```
 layout-xhdpi
 drawable-xhdpi
```

Comment: I haven't got different layouts folders because they're the same

Comment: But you have to make the drawable folders with respective dpi if you still have one layout folder.

Comment: Yes...in fact i have different drawable folders (one for each resolution) but just one layout

Comment: anybody else?? i still have the problem :(

Comment: is there a simple drawable folder ? if so delete that.